# How to rewrite this rhythm from common time to 12/8 time?

Tags: theory, notation, rhythm, time-signatures, tuplet

How might one go about rewriting the following rhythm into a time signature of 12/8? I initially figured we could just notate each set of beamed eighth-notes with 4:6 above them to indicate that four notes should be played in the span of 6. However, I'm not sure if there's a more proper way to indicate this and if that'll work because the last note is tied across the barline.
Additionally, is it conventional to write 4 beamed eighth-notes in this manner? Would it be more proper to have a quarter note, two sets of 2 beamed eighth notes and then another quarter note for each bar, or would some other depiction be more appropriate? Thanks

[image]

Comment: I don't have access to a score editor atm but for the effect to be the same in compound quadruple time, it would be two notes in the time of three 4 times ie four sets of duplets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this two ways.  I don't think beaming in fours would add to the clarity, but I wouldn't shoot you for doing it!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the effect to be the same in compound quadruple time, it would be two notes in the time of three 4 times ie four sets of duplets.

So, in other words, this times two.

[image]